# Custom Form Button

Tags: javascript, html

Ok Guys, i have this code:

```
<a class="button" href="#"><span>SEND</span></a>
```

how i can transtorm this in a submit form button?

i have tried this, but dont worlks...

```
        <div class="contato_form" id="contato_form">                    
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="javascript:envia_contato();">
            <p><label for="nome">Name:</label><input class="campo_contato" type="text" name="nome" id="nome" /></p>
            <p><label for="email">Email:</label><input class="campo_contato" type="text" name="email" id="email" /></p>
        </form>
    <div class="clear">
    <p><a class="botao" href="#" onclick="javascript:envia_contato();"><span>SUBMIT</span></a></p>
    </div>
    </br>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of problems.

1. Your **form *action*** should not be the same as the *onclick of the submit buton*. The form action should be the page which will receive the data you send. So there you have to put a page which is not only HTML but a page server side handled (i.e. PHP, ASP, ASP.NET, JSP, etc.).
2. Your javascript function `envia_contato` is not defined in the code you shared, so you have to define it somewhere in the HTML (using a `script` tag) before using it (like Bhanu suggested):

   ```
   <script>
   function envia_contato()
   {
       form1.submit();
   }
   </script>
   <div class="contato_form" id="contato_form">
       <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="/echo/json/">
           <p>
               <label for="nome">Name:</label>
               <input class="campo_contato" type="text" name="nome" id="nome" />
           </p>
           <p>
               <label for="email">Email:</label>
               <input class="campo_contato" type="text" name="email" id="email" />
           </p>
       </form>
       <div class="clear">
           <p><a class="botao" href="#" onclick="envia_contato(); return false;"><span>SUBMIT</span></a></p>
       </div>
       <br/>
   </div>
   ```

   Or you may discard the `envia_contato` function and call the submit directly (like JK did):

   ```
   <p><a class="botao" href="#" onclick="form1.submit(); return false;"><span>SUBMIT</span></a></p>
   ```

   The `return false;` at the end of the onclick will avoid further events to be raised after that javascript is called, so if you return false the redirección to `#` will not be done (such redirection is not really important most times, but this way it will do exactly what you need, and you don't need that redirection).

And the following things are not real problems because in most HTML parsers will work anyway (but you may be interested in knowing this anyway):

1. But you don't need the `javascript:` when you attach javascript events (like onclick), you need it when something else is expected (like in the `href` which expects a just a link and not javascript, so you use the prefix to define javascript in there).
2. Your **br** tag had the `/` before the `br` and it should be just `<br>` or `<br/>`.

Comment: +1 small addition is to add return false: `onclick="envia_contato(); return false;"` otherwise certain browsers might cause weird problems..

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<a class="botao" href="#" onclick="form1.submit()">
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to do submit form on anchor tag `onclick` event

```
function envia_contato()
{
  document.form1.submit();
}
```

Comment: try in action of a form define the path where you want that form action